# Vector Visualisation of regression model vs scatter plot style

Tags: econometrics, statistics, linear-algebra

I wrote [another post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/55699/intuition-of-linear-algebra-visualisation-for-regression) discussing the intuition of visualising OLS regression.

I wanted to go a bit deeper here visualising the difference between a vector/matrix approach, and the non-linear algebra approach. The thing that has really struck me is that both approaches visualise the same data in totally different ways.

**Visualisation 1**

Take the 'model' that is the plane that lives in $\mathbb{R^3}$ that minimises the sum of squared distances between each point on the plane corresponding to our pair of independent variable points $x_{1i}$ & $x_{2i}$, and the point $y_i$. These individual distance are our estimated residuals call them $\bar μ_i$

Here our data points are the vectors $(x_{1i}, x_{2i}, y_i)$ where each component is the $i^{th}$ observation of a different variable, and $y_i$. And our plane is the one that minimises the squared distances between itself and these points.

**Key point:** Here the dimensionality of our space is **determined by the number of different variables**? And then all the observations are just points in this space?

**Visualisation 2**

Vector form: In vector form we instead have single vectors in $n$ dimensional space, whereby our number of observations defines $n$.
Vector $y$ and each vector $x_i$ form $n$ dimensional vectors in this space. In contrast to the previous visualisation, here the entries of our vectors are individual observations of the same variable.

The span of these $x_i$ vectors will form a hyperplane $X$, in this $n$ dimensional space.  Our vector $\hat y$ which represents our model, is the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto the plane $X$, and the coefficients that define the linear combination of $x_i$ vectors that give $\hat y$ are the weights of our $β_ι$ parameters in our model.

**Key point:** The dimensionality of the space is actually **determined by the number of observations**?

**Questions:**

1. It sounds simple but i've never seen the same set of points be described differently like this. Is it perhaps speaking to some fundamental relationship between row and column vectors? I'd love some more thoughts to this observation?
2. Even though these different interpretations achieve the same thing. The second feels  more rigid. For example:

- It makes immediately clear that our vectors of independent variable must be LI, otherwise we cannot have the Inverse Matrix required.
- Similarly this implies that we must have more observations than variables otherwise the Matrix would be singular. However the non linear algebra visualisation, where our space dimension is given by the amount of variables makes it much les obvious that we must have more observations than variables.
- It's also visually less intuitive, a plane cutting through a bunch of points in space kind of feels familiar. But finding a single vector within a plane to minimise the distance to another vector just feels... unsatisfying? I'm struggling to put into words quite what's bothering me. Maybe those more familiar can give me some helpful nudges?